# Turning 2 one dimensional arrays into 1 two dimensional array Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, numpy-ndarray

How can I add 2 one dimensional arrays together into one 2 dimensional array. I want to  add `a` and `b` together so that I get the expected output.

```
a = np.array([0,1,0,1,0,1])
b = np.array([38846,51599,51599,52598,290480,360467])
```

Expected Output

```
[[     0  38846]
 [     1  51599]
 [     0  51599]
 [     1  52598]
 [     0 290480]
 [     1 360467]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `np.stack`:

```
print(np.stack([a, b], axis=1))
```

Output:

```
[[     0  38846]
 [     1  51599]
 [     0  51599]
 [     1  52598]
 [     0 290480]
 [     1 360467]]
```

Comment: I think he wants to combine them as columns, `np.stack([a, b], axis=1)`

Comment: @hpaulj Oh thanks for the catch... I misread the question